# Search for and replace SSN and/or Credit Card in String Java

Tags: java, regex, json, string

I'm looking to search a string of text for a credit card number and/or SSN in Java and then replace that match with a placeholder. For some reason I can't figure this out so any help would be appreciated.

Below is a method I wrote. I think my Regex pattern is off because it never finds either one. Searching around google/stackoverflow I surprisingly can't find a good example of someone doing this before so I thought this would be good question to add to the community.

I will need to search all formats where a CC or SSN might occur i.e 111-11-1111/111111111/4111111111111111/4111-1111-1111-1111. I need to search all possible credit cards as well (AMEX, VISA, DISCOVER etc)

Looking for the most creative way to do this!

```
private static final String ssnPattern = "^\\d{3}-?\\d{2}-?\\d{4}$";
private static final String ccPattern = ".*^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]    {14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\\d{3})\\d{11})$.*";

private static final Pattern ssnDetector = Pattern.compile(ssnPattern);
private static final Pattern ccDetector = Pattern.compile(ccPattern);
private static final String CC_PLACEHOLDER = "{CREDIT_CARD_REDACTED}";
private static final String SSN_PLACEHOLDER = "{SSN_REDACTED}";

public static void main(String[] args){
    String body3 = "Here is my credit card 4111111111111111 and my SSN 111-22-3333";
    body3 = redactCC(body3);
    body3 = redactSSN(body3);
    logger.info(body3);
}

public static String redactSSN(String data){
   Matcher m = ssnDetector.matcher(data);
   return m.replaceAll(SSN_PLACEHOLDER);
}

public static String redactCC(String data){
   Matcher m = ccDetector.matcher(data);
   return m.replaceAll(CC_PLACEHOLDER);
}
```

Comment: Your credit card regex is too complicated for me to look at.  But I think the `^` and `$` in your SSN regex are causing problems.  With those, it will match _only_ if the source string consists **only** of an SSN.  `^` means that the three digits have to occur at the beginning of the string, and `$` means that the four digits have to occur at the end of the string.  The `^` and `$` in the credit card pattern aren't helpful either.  Maybe you want to use `\b`?  That matches a "word boundary", so that it requires the SSN or credit card number to be their own "words".

Comment: If you use `\b`, make sure you double the backslash in the string literal.  (If you don't, it will try to match a backspace character.)

Comment: The CC Regex is still needed though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ^, no $, no .* and removed the spaces before {14}

```
private static final String ssnPattern = "\\d{3}-?\\d{2}-?\\d{4}";
private static final String ccPattern = "(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|" +
 "6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|" + 
 "(?:2131|1800|35\\d{3})\\d{11}|" +
 "(?:4\\d{3}|5[1-5]\\d{2}|6011|7\\d{3})-?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}|3[4,7]\\d{13})";
```

Fix typo m.group

```
while (n.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found a " + n.group() + ".");
```

Comment: This doesn't properly do all CC's and doesn't work for dashed patterns.

Comment: Add this for CC validation - "((4\\d{3})|(5[1-5]\\d{2})|(6011)|(7\\d{3}))-?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}|3[4,7]\\d{13}" Reference:https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Validation_Regex_Repository

Comment: My answer used your regular expression. But I added this one, too.